# Comparing timestamp with sysdate in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datetime, where-clause

Hello I am trying to get the status of running of job for each day. At database end the job runs at 18:00 to 18:10. There is one column which I am fetching and it is a time stamp like `29-APR-20 20.08.30`

I now as this job runs daily so I want to know the status of today's run. It should not return any row for today's day if the job hasn't started yet.

I put the below where condition :

```
where CAST(log_date as date) > sysdate-1
```

Now as today is 30 APR so sysdate-1 is 29april. So it should find a column with date as 30th april but since the job hasn't been run so far so now rows shoud come.

But in output I am receiving`29-APR-20 20.08.30`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you want:

```
where log_date > trunc(sysdate)
```

This checks if a row exists whose `log_date` belongs to the current *day* (without the time component). On the other hand, your original expression checked if a row exists within the last 24 hours - which, if you job runs at a fixed time on a daily basis, will always return something.